# Postfix operators in while loops

Tags: c++, while-loop, postfix-operator

I was looking through some C++ code today when I stumbled upon this:

```
while (c--) {
    a = (a + 1) % n;
    while(arr[a]) a = (a + 1) % n;
}
```

c was an integer. Don't *while* loops take boolean expressions to be evaluated? I know 1 and 0 are fine because they represent true and false, respectively, but in this case c was taking on values other than 0 and 1. What does this do?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Boolean_conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that isn't 0 is considered true, so this would loop until C=0.

Could just be a simple case of "using less code"